# Combine - merging multiple shared filters

Tags: ios, asynchronous, rx-swift, combine

I've been working with RxSwift for a while now, just switched to Combine and I am trying to wrap my head around this specific `.filter` behaviour. Here's a short playground example:

```swift
import Combine

let publisher = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    .publisher
    .share()

let filter1 = publisher
    .filter { $0 == 1 }
    .print("filter1")

let filter2 = publisher
    .filter { $0 == 2 }
    .print("filter2")

Publishers
    .Merge(filter1, filter2)
    .sink {
        print("Result is: \($0)")
    }
```

the output is

```
filter1: receive subscription: (Multicast)
filter1: request unlimited
filter1: receive value: (1)
Result is: 1
filter1: receive finished
filter2: receive subscription: (Multicast)
filter2: request unlimited
filter2: receive finished
```

What surprises me is that `Result is: 2` is never called because the stream finishes. I could remove `.share()` operator which would result in receiving both values as I'd expect

```
filter1: receive subscription: ([1])
filter1: request unlimited
filter1: receive value: (1)
Result is: 1
filter1: receive finished
filter2: receive subscription: ([2])
filter2: request unlimited
filter2: receive value: (2)
Result is: 2
filter2: receive finished
```

But what if my publisher is an API call and I don't want to create a duplicate network request? Which is exactly the case I am trying to handle now and it's also why I need to use `.share()` operator.

Any better explanation why is this happening and how to handle a case where you want to filter a stream, do a separate logic in each stream and then merge the results back together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are a couple of different things going on here.

**First**, the `[1, 2, 3].publisher` works different than `Observable.from([1, 2, 3])`. The latter emits the values once per cycle, while the former emits all the values back to back. The Publisher example works more like this in Rx:

```
Observable<Int>.create { observer in
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].forEach {
        observer.onNext($0)
    }
    observer.onCompleted()
    return Disposables.create()
}
```

Because of this, in the `Observable.from` case, the emissions are *not* complete by the time the filter2 observable is subscribed to. So even if you omit the `share()` both "Result is: 1" and "Result is: 2" will be emitted.

**Second**, the `share()` operator also works differently. By default, the RxSwift share operator will reset the Observable once all subscriptions are disposed (it's a reference counting share). In the Combine case, the share operator makes the publisher connectable and then connects to it. Essentially, it's the same as the `.share(replay: 0, scope: .forever)` operator in RxSwift (something I have never needed in Rx BTW).

So the Rx code that is equivalent to the Combine code you posted is actually this:

```
let observable = emitSequence([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    .share(replay: 0, scope: .forever)

let filter1ʹ = observable
    .filter { $0 == 1 }
    .debug("filterʹ1")

let filter2ʹ = observable
    .filter { $0 == 2 }
    .debug("filterʹ2")

Observable.merge(filter1ʹ, filter2ʹ)
    .subscribe(onNext: {
        print("Resultʹ is: \($0)")
    })

func emitSequence<S>(_ sequence: S) -> Observable<S.Element> where S: Sequence {
    Observable.create { observer in
        sequence.forEach {
            observer.onNext($0)
        }
        observer.onCompleted()
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

All this said the practical aspect of dealing with an API call is fine. In that case, the assumption is that the call won't immediately return (it will take a cycle at least) and since it's one-shot, as long as you make sure you aren't resubscribing to the Observable, the fact that `share()` doesn't reset isn't a problem.

Comment: Some might call what is happening in Combine a bug, others might call it a difference in philosophy. Personally, I think it's a difference in working with an API that has been battle tested for over 6 years vs working with one that is only a couple of years old.